# ¿Cómo sumar el resultado impreso con los otros en Python?

Tags: python

He intentado sumar el resultado que me imprime de los múltiplos de 3 del 1 al 50, pero no sé cómo sumar todos esos resultados e imprimirlo al final.

Tengo esto:

```
def multiplo():

    """
    problema: hacer una funcion que sumen los multiplos de 3 del 1 al 50.

    entrada: numeros.
    salida: suma total de todos.

    """

    numero = 1
    a = 0 

    while numero <= 50:

        n = 3
        total = n * numero
        numero = numero + 1
        print(total)

multiplo()
```

Comment: Tienes que verificar que el número es múltiplo de 3, usa el operador `%` que devuelve el residuo. Si es múltiplo, sumas el número a tu total.

Comment: Los multipos de 3 del uno al 50 suman 408: `3+6+9+12+15+18+21+24+27+30+33+36+39+42+45+48`

Answer (score 1):

Existen muchas posibilidades, usando un while y obteniendo los múltiplos sumando 3 en cada iteración:

```
def multiplo():
    numero = 3
    total = 0 

    while numero <= 50:
        total = total + numero
        numero = numero + 3
    print(total)
```

Con un  `for` y usando `range`, empezando en 3 y terminando en el limite+1. Como paso especificamos 3:

```
def multiplo():
    res = 0
    for n in range(3, 51, 3):
        res = res + n
    print(res)
```

Lo mismo que lo anterior pero usando compresión de listas:

```
def multiplo():
    print(sum((n for n in range(3, 51, 3))))
```

Como en tu código dice:

> entrada: numeros.

Sospecho que puede que lo que se espera es que la función reciva los número entre los cuales se dean obtener los múltiplos de 3. En este caso podemos modificar las funciones anteriores usando la operación módulo `%` y un condicional, de forma que si la división da resto 0 sabemos que el numero es multiplo de 3:

```
def multiplo(n, limInf, limSup):
    total = 0 
    while limInf <= limSup:
        if limInf%n == 0:
            total = total + limInf
        limInf = limInf + 1
    print(total)

multiplo(3,1,50)
```

.

```
def multiplo(n, limInf, limSup):
    res = 0
    for i in range(limInf, limSup+1):
        if i % n == 0:
            res = res + i
    print(res)

multiplo(3,1,50)
```

.

```
def multiplo3(n, limInf, limSup):
    print(sum((i for i in range(limInf, limSup+1) if i%n == 0)))

multiplo(3,1,50)
```

En este caso a la función se le pasa como primer parámetro el número cuyos múltiplos deseamos sumar, como segundo el límite inferior y como tercero el límite superior. De esta forma la función permite calcular las suma de los multiplos de cualquier numero entre dos limites dados. Como siempre hay muchas otras formas, esto son solo ejemplos.

Comment: Aqui está la respuesta correcta =)

Answer (score 0):

La suma en realidad la estas realizando y almacenando en la variable `total`, La impresión del total debe estar al mismo nivel del `while`, ya que dentro imprime en cada bucle la suma, si se coloca al nivel del `while` imprimirá el resultado de `total` al terminar el bucle:

```
   while numero <= 50:

        n = 3
        total = n * numero
        numero = numero + 1
        #print(total)

   print(total)
```

Resultado:

```
150
```

Answer (score 0):

Tal como lo está haciendo solo vas a conseguir imprimir el último paso del ciclo, es decir el último múltiplo de 3 (150), simplemente porque no estás acumulando `total = total + ...`, 
Una forma de resolverlo es la siguiente:

```
numero = 3
n = 1
total = 0
while n <= 50:
    total = total + (n * numero)
    n = n + 1

print(total)
```

y una forma mucho más "pythonica":

```
print(sum(n*3 for n in range(1,50)))
```

incluso, mucho mejor lo que te comentó @FJSevilla porque ahorramos la multiplicación, podemos generar directamente los múltiples de 3

```
print(sum ([n for n in range(3, 51, 3)]))
```

Comment: Aquí el resultado es 3,825

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta mal planteado.

Recuerda que te estan solicitando sumar los multiplos de 3 entre 1 y 50

Es necesario recordar que un numero es multiplo de 3 si el residuo de la división de ese numero entre 3 es 0, por ende lo primero que debes hacer dentro de la iteración, es verificar el residuo de la división de ese numero entre 3 con la utilización del operador `%`

Con respecto a tu planteamiento inicial, no vas a mostrar el resultado final ya que para cada iteración estas mostrando el total hasta el momento.

En resumen tendrías los siguientes pasos:

1. Iterar entre 1 y 50
2. verificar si el numero es multiplo de 3
3. De ser multiplo de 3, sumarlo al acumulador
4. Al final de la iteración ,mostrar el acumulador

Resultando algo como:

```
def multiplos_de_3():
    total = 0
    for i in range(1, 51):
        if (i % 3) == 0:
            print "%d es multiplo de 3" % (i)
            total += i

    print "El total de sumar los multiplos de 3 entre 1 y 50 es: %d" % (total)

multiplos_de_3()
```

La salida fue:

```
3 es multiplo de 3
6 es multiplo de 3
9 es multiplo de 3
12 es multiplo de 3
15 es multiplo de 3
18 es multiplo de 3
21 es multiplo de 3
24 es multiplo de 3
27 es multiplo de 3
30 es multiplo de 3
33 es multiplo de 3
36 es multiplo de 3
39 es multiplo de 3
42 es multiplo de 3
45 es multiplo de 3
48 es multiplo de 3
El total de sumar los multiplos de 3 entre 1 y 50 es: 408
```